# How do I know which firewall is running on Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, firewall, ufw, firestarter

I've always used ufw by default, even though I also had installed Firestarter

After upgrading from Ubuntu 9.04 to 9.10, by way of Update Manager, I've found ufw disabled (when I look at gufw).

How do I know which firewall is running at any momment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type ufw status into a command prompt. 
Assesories>Terminal
Type "ufw status" without quotes. 
You may need to type "sudo ufw status". 
Firestarter is a GUI for the ufw firewall.

Comment: So both GUFW and Firestarter use ufw?

Comment: @lamcro: both ufw and firestarter are using iptables. ;)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know...Ubuntu has no default firewall, because there is nothing to protect (all services listening on a loopback device).